# MySQL: linking tables with extracted sum of column per row

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

MySQL: I need to link these tables and extracted sum of one of the column per row in the resulting table

**tblRedemption**

```
+---------------------+
| OrderID | OrderDesc | 
+---------------------+
| 1000001 | aaaa      | 
| 1000002 | bbbb      | 
| 1000003 | cccc      |
| 1000004 | dddd      |
+---------------------+
```

**tblLink**

```
+------------------------+
| SubmissionID | OrderID | 
+------------------------+
| 201          | 1000001 | 
| 202          | 1000002 | 
| 203          | 1000003 |
| 204          | 1000004 |
+------------------------+
```

**tblSubmissions**

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| SubmissionID | Name | Mobile     | Amount | 
+-------------------------------------------+
| 150          | Amy  | 1111111111 | 10     |
| 200          | Bob  | 2222222222 | 20     |
| 201          | Carl | 3333333333 | 30     |
| 202          | Dave | 4444444444 | 10     |
| 203          | Carl | 3333333333 | 25     |
| 204          | Fin  | 5555555555 | 35     |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected Results:**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SubmissionID | Name | mobile     | OrderDesc | Amount | TotalAmount |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 201          | Carl | 3333333333 | aaaa      | 30     | 55          |
| 203          | Carl | 3333333333 | bbbb      | 25     | 55          |
| 204          | Fin  | 5555555555 | cccc      | 35     | 35          |
| 202          | Dave | 4444444444 | dddd      | 10     | 10          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

1. Number of tblSubmission is a bigger list than the tblredemption.
2. There are customers with multiple entries tblSubmission identified by their mobile (see Carl).
3. The table tbLink joins the 2 tblSubmission and tblRdemption.
4. The resulting table also needs a new column which holds the total amount for each particular customer (by mobile).
5. The expected results needs to include:

   - The SubmissionID and OrderDesc from the "tblRedemption" table.
   - The Name, Mobile and Amount from the tblSubmissions table.

All my queries ether gives me a small subset or just one row, or "multiple rows returned".

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't the predilection for prefixing table names with 'tbl' become wearying. If it's in a database, it seems to me reasonable to suspect that it might be a table, and if it's a view,.. well there a little 'v_' might not go amiss

Comment: Provide your queries. Is it a homework?

Comment: Hi Strawberry, thanks,  but unfortunately the db is inherited. And I'm slowly getting use to the naming convention now.
:0)

Andrew, no this is not homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select l.submissionid, s.name, s.mobile, s.amount, t.totalamount
from tbllink l
inner join tblsubmissions s on l.submissionid = s.submissionid
inner join (
  select `name`, sum(amount) as totalamount
  from tblsubmissions
  group by `name`
) t on s.`name` = t.`name`
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ea56a/5

Same query totalled by mobile number

```
select l.submissionid, s.name, s.mobile, s.amount, t.totalamount
from tbllink l
inner join tblsubmissions s on l.submissionid = s.submissionid
inner join (
  select mobile, sum(amount) as totalamount
  from tblsubmissions
  group by mobile
) t on s.mobile = t.mobile
```

EDIT:

Including order desc is relatively easy also. Let's see:

```
select l.submissionid, s.name, s.mobile, r.orderdesc, s.amount, t.totalamount
from tbllink l
inner join tblredemption r on l.orderid = r.orderid
inner join tblsubmissions s on l.submissionid = s.submissionid
inner join (
  select `name`, sum(amount) as totalamount
  from tblsubmissions
  group by `name`
) t on s.`name` = t.`name`
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63540/2

Tables

```
create table tblredemption (orderid int, orderdesc varchar(100));
insert into tblredemption values (1000001, 'aaaa'), (1000002, 'bbbb'), (1000003, 'cccc'), (1000004, 'dddd');

create table tbllink (submissionid int, orderid int);
insert into tbllink values (201,1000001), (202,1000002), (203,1000003), (204,1000004);

create table tblsubmissions (
  submissionid int,
  `name` varchar(20),
  mobile varchar(20),
  amount int
);
insert into tblsubmissions values
( 150          , 'Amy'  , '1111111111', 10     ),
( 200          , 'Bob'  , '2222222222' , 20     ),
( 201          , 'Carl' , '3333333333' , 30     ),
( 202          , 'Dave' , '4444444444' , 10     ),
( 203          , 'Carl' , '3333333333' , 25     ),
( 204          , 'Fin'  , '5555555555' , 35     );
```

Results:

```
| submissionid | name |     mobile | orderdesc | amount | totalamount |
|--------------|------|------------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|          201 | Carl | 3333333333 |      aaaa |     30 |          55 |
|          203 | Carl | 3333333333 |      cccc |     25 |          55 |
|          202 | Dave | 4444444444 |      bbbb |     10 |          10 |
|          204 |  Fin | 5555555555 |      dddd |     35 |          35 |
```

Comment: Hi zedfoxus, Thanks for this! it works.
Unfortunately, I very stupidly forgot to add the crucial "OrderDesc" column which needed to be displayed in the results. 

Please see my amended description (point 5 and the resulting table)

Comment: I have updated the answer with orderdesc. If you find this helpful, please feel free to bring closure to your question by accepting the answer. If this is not helpful, please let me know how I can help.

Comment: Hi Zedfoxus, this was indeed helpful getting me closer. 

But this seems to be dependent on the firstname being unique. i tried updating the name to mobile in the second join and i need to test this thoroughly but think this works!

Thanks again!